# explaining this declaration of the global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this quite a lot at the top of scripts but I'm not completely sure what it means, can anyone explain?

```
var whatevername = whatevername || {};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the OR operator to set default values. If `whatevername` has been set it will be used, otherwise a new empty object will be used.

An example:

```
function sayHi(options){
    options = options || {};
    if (options.useAlert){
        alert("hi");
    } else {
        console.log("hi");
    }
}
```

In this case you can always use the options parameter, even if it isn't passed to the function:

```
sayHi(); 
sayHi({"useAlert": true});
```

In the first case `{}` will be used and options.useAlert will be undefined. In the if statement that's the same as it being set to false and `console.log` will be used to print.

The OR operator is usually used like this:

> if (hasAnEmailAddress || hasAPhoneNumber) {contactPerson()}

If `hasAnEmailAddress` is true the operator will return the value of `hasAnEmailAddress` instead of `hasAPhoneNumber`. If it isn't true the value of the second argument, `hasAPhoneNumber` will be returned.

That logic is used when setting default values: If the first argument is falsy return the second argument - even if it isn't a boolean value.

Comment: For example you may use it for the module pattern: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 2):

it initializes `whatevername` with an empty object if `whatevername` hasn't already been initialized.

Equivalent code

```
if(!whatevername) whatevername  = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a lot of languages, you will see this done with a ternary operator, which I think makes it very clear what's going on. Example:

```
var whatevername = (whatevername != NULL) ? whatevername : {};
```

In Javascript, if the || operator evaluates to truthy, it will not return a boolean value as one might expect, but the value of the operand which was last evaluated. Therefor, if whatevername is null, it will return a new object, otherwise it will return whatevername. Ruby does this as well, just to name another example of this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is a default value statement. `||` is the symbol for OR, as you probably know.

The statement reads "set whatevername to whatevername OR an empty object". The OR will pick the first of the two objects that reads to a truthy value (not empty, not false). If whatevername was set, you'll get whatevername. If not (or if set to null), you'll get an empty object.